# callback method doesn't fired upon click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having an issue which my callback function doesn't fired upon a click event.
my js code is as following:

```
this.tabList = [{callbackFunc: this.firstPrint, isBtnSelected: this.isASelected}, {callbackFunc:this.secondPrint, isBtnSelected: this.isBSelected}]
```

my html code concludes a tab which inside the tab there is a button which clickable:

```
<div class="tabs-container">
<button ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.tabList"
        ng-click="$ctrl.selectTab($index)">
 <tool-bar-button on-click="tab.callbackFunc"
                  is-button-selected="tab.isBtnSelected">
 </tool-bar-button>
</button>
```

the callback function doesn't gets called, i think the issue is reffred to the list of objects because if i do:
on-click="$ctrl.firstPrint"
then the function gets fired.

Comment: is function firstPrint defined at the moment when you define tabList?

Comment: the tabList defined in the component constructor and the firstPrint is the component function

Comment: just for sure, did you try `console.log(this.firstPrint)` just before `this.tabList = [..` ?

Comment: can you provide <tool-bar-button> directive js code

Comment: @bigless - yes i did and it printed ok

Comment: @Angular_10 - the toolBarButton.controller received the onClick in binding and have a buttonClick event which there he activate the callback